# How can I protect my C++ application from being decompiled?

Tags: visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: How to Make it Harder for Hacker/Cracker to Get Around or Bypass the Licensing Check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensi)
>   [Protect C++ program against decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113884/protect-c-program-against-decompiling)

How can I protect my visual C++ windows form application from being decompiled?
Is there a way?

Thanks guys !

Comment: Windows Forms? Then it's a .NET program, right? In that case, use an obfuscator.

Comment: Simple answer is no - unless you stand behind the person that you gave the program to.

Comment: This topic really is not language dependent, see [C#: How to Make it Harder for Hacker/Cracker to Get Around or Bypass the Licensing Check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensi)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect it to a certain point from decompilation  you can always use some protection software like an obfuscator or encrypter.

There is a vast number of products that can do this varying in price (from free to very expensive), complexity and implementation.

You might want to check http://www.safenet-inc.com/.

Comment: Hello McKracken, i have try using a Obfuscator program to protect my   Visual-C++ Application but it says "Is not a valid .NET assembly."  I tried on a C# Application and it works great? Does a Obfuscator program only work on C# Application and not on C++?

Comment: There is a bunch of different obfuscators, some of them work only on .NET projects. Which one did you try? And please, give more details on how your project is done and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Miglt want to try something from here: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/

Comment: I am new in Programming and my English is not soo good!So its difficult to understand sorry.I have tried alot of different obfuscators programmes and they all give me errors like these http://i.imgur.com/t1ovt.png What is Assembly?My Project is build in Microsoft Visual Studio as "Visual C++ Windows Forms Application"

Comment: Why Is this closed? I still didn't find a way! I am trying everything and it's not working. I don't know what am I doing wrong! Please reopen this. Thank you in advance